# Postgresql query many to many relationship with left join and use where clouse not show data

Tags: postgresql

I have three table, table_1 (id), table_2(id), table_pivot(tbl1_id, tbl2_id). When I use query like this:

```
select * 
from public.table_1 t1 
left join public.table_pivot tp on tp.tbl1_id = t1.id and tp.user_id = 1 
left join public.table_2 t2 on t2.id = tp.tbl2_id;
```

Data from table_1 is show. But when I use where condition. Like this:

```
select * 
from public.table_1 t1 
left join public.table_pivot tp on tp.tbl1_id = t1.id 
left join public.table_2 t2 on t2.id = tp.tbl2_id
where tp.user_id = 1;
```

Data from table_1 not show.

I hope advance can help explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: move `tp.user_id = 1` into the join condition for tp

Comment: Can you answer the question with query example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including a where clause on an outer joined table, effectively converts the join into an inner join.  If there are no matching values in table_pivot, then
you will get no results at all.  This is standard sql.

Comment: Can you give me query example?

Comment: I was explaining why your first query returns answers and your second doesn't.  Your first query is the correct way to deal with an extra constraint on the join.  As I said, if you put it into a where clause, the join is effectively promoted from outer to inner, because the where operates on the entire select and can only operate on matched values.